# OpenGL context with Cocoa (OS X)

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl

I am trying to programmatically create a Cocoa window with an OpenGL context for an OS X application.  I have been unable to find an example online which does not use the Interface Builder for creating a window and OpenGL view.

All I want is for `glClear` to make my window magenta (0xFF00FF).  However, the window remains white.

Here is my project:

#### AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow *window;
    NSOpenGLContext *openGLContext;
}

@property (assign) NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) NSOpenGLContext *openGLContext;

- (void)draw;

@end
```

#### AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize openGLContext;

static NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute glAttributes[] = {
    0
};

- (void)draw {
    NSLog(@"Drawing...");

    [self.openGLContext makeCurrentContext];

    glClearColor(1, 0, 1, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    [self.openGLContext flushBuffer];
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 200);

    self.window = [[[NSWindow alloc]
        initWithContentRect:frame
        styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
        backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
        defer:NO] autorelease];
    [self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];

    NSOpenGLPixelFormat *pixelFormat
        = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:glAttributes];
    self.openGLContext = [[NSOpenGLContext alloc]
        initWithFormat:pixelFormat shareContext:nil];
    [self.openGLContext setView:[self.window contentView]];

    [NSTimer
        scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1
        target:self
        selector:@selector(draw)
        userInfo:nil
        repeats:YES];
}

- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)_app {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

#### main.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **) argv);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `-[NSOpenGLContext flushBuffer]` says:

> **Discussion**
>
> If the receiver is not a double-buffered context, this call does nothing.

You can cause your context to be double-buffered by including `NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer` in your pixel format attributes. Alternatively, you can call `glFlush()` instead of `-[NSOpenGLContext flushBuffer]` and leave your context single-buffered.

Comment: Good catch.  I tried both of your solutions (adding `NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer` and calling `glFlush`), and neither changed the application; I still get a white screen and not the magenta I expect.

Comment: Is there any chance you can upload a copy of your test Xcode project somewhere? The change I described was sufficient to fix the sample application I put together with your code snippets, so there must be some remaining disconnect.

Comment: I recreated the project and now your solutions work.  Odd; must have been a broken project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for the pixel format attributes instead.

```
NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute glAttributes[] =
{
    NSOpenGLPFAColorSize, 24,
    NSOpenGLPFAAlphaSize, 8,
    NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer,
    NSOpenGLPFAAccelerated,
    0
};
```

I've tested it and you get the magenta screen you were looking for.